# How to find mailbox details using Custom attributes EWS

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there any ways to get the mailbox details using the custom attributes of the mailbox. I'm using EWS service.

[image: Custome attributes]

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this in EWS, if you are using Office365 you can use the Graph for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview. If its OnPrem then look at using a LDAP and access Active directory. If you really need to do it via EWS use EWS to create a Custom property on the Root Mailbox folder etc